# Drawing shapes in Xamarin programmatically. Allow overlap and transparency

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, drawing, stacklayout

I'm very new to Xamarin, but not C#. I'm trying to draw concentric circles and various shapes to a StackLayout, where traditionally I would use a Canvas in WPF.

I'm trying to avoid using SkiaSharp - and I wondered what control I should be using, if not a StackLayout? I can get it to draw shapes, but they clip one another and don't overlap as I want. See top left circles in image:

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code (as text) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A StackLayout doesn't stack in z-direction. It stacks either in y-direction (`Orientation="Vertical"`), which is the default, or x-direction (`Orientation="Horizontal"`). To "stack" them in z-direction, you could use a Grid instead. Why don't you want to use SkiaSharp? It's much more perfomant than Shapes.

Comment: I don't wish to use a control that "stacks". I want something that functions like a canvas where I can draw in the x and y. Using a grid has worked - thank you.

Comment: Here is docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/circle. Here is example code - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/skiasharpforms-demos/

Comment: @DenysKazakov He wants to avoid SkiaSharp for some reason. I would agree that SkiaSharp is the most suitable option for Xamarin.Forms.